# Xcode 7 beta 1 view doesn't fit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

In all previous versions of Xcode, my storyboard for this app was fine, but since updating to the Xcode 7 beta, running on the simulator and on device (iOS 9) the view size seems to be distorted. Similar to an app that hasn't been optimised for iPhone 6/6 Plus, but the height is also shortened.

Any reasons why this would be happening? Thanks

Comment: Are you using AutolayoutConstraints?

Comment: Yes, I have auto layout and size classes turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a correctly sized launch image for iPhone 6 in the assets folder. This makes the view fit perfectly.